# Django plugable news story application

Tags: looking-for-a-script, blog, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Are there any plugable django blog apps that can be embeded into existing pages or templates. It doesn't have to be a full fledged blogging engine. The features I am looking for are:

- Displaying multiple stories with 'read more' button. Display should be like news items on a news-agregator, without the regular features of blogs like commenting or social networking buttons.
- Url for each story
- Support for pagination to limit the number of stories that can apper on the home page.
- Loadable on to the existing pages or templates.

If there are no such apps, suggestions for how the modules (views, models, urls) can be written are welcome.

Comment: more or less a dup of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624750/where-can-i-find-a-pluggable-blog-app-for-django

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a comparison of django blogs (and other apps you can use, btw):

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/